# How can I learn iOS Test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing

I use Xcode 7.2 to develop an app. Now I want to study to test iOS. I read the test introduction from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/01-introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132. 
How can I learn more about XCTestCase？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many tutorials over the internet.The following few tutorials may help you better understanding.

http://rshankar.com/test-driven-development-in-ios-beginners-tutorial-part-1/

http://rshankar.com/test-driven-development-in-ios-beginners-tutorial-part-2/

http://mobileoop.com/learning-unit-testing-in-xcode-5

http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/

Answer (score 0):

raywenderlich and cocoacontrols are the most usefull website to learn anything about iOS.